# Give permission to other users to access disk

Tags: mount, disk, chmod, chown

I created a new **disk** and mounted it and made entries in fstab file but the disk can only be accessed by the root user.How to
1.Give permission of read and write to the disk for other users
2.Give execute permission to only sudo users

Comment: I would suggest you look at man permissions Enter that command in terminal to read the man pages. You can also do this with a browser and a search engine.

Comment: The used filesystem is also relevant, what is it, NTFS, ext4, fat32 ot what?